# NSView subclass with IBOutlets and IBActions

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsview

I have an NSView subclass that is used for displaying a custom object. The drawing logic is all in methods on the subclass. There is no view controller associated with this view.

I have added a couple of controls next to this view in Interface Builder that will be used to control the display of the object.

Is it OK to have these controls connected to `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s on the view? I know that it's possible, but is it poor design? Should I be using an NSViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is completely fine and it's how things are supposed to connect together.  There is no need to use an `NSViewController` as it only really helps manage the creation of the view from a `.nib` file and it can still only manage one view.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason I'm asking is that the rest of the controls in this window are connected to various objects in IB that are subclassed from `NSObject` to do specific tasks. I suppose rather than `NSViewController`, I would consider create a custom controller class to deal with these new controls.

Comment: @c.cam108 It's not clear what you mean by 'deal with these new controls'?  If they are buttons then they just fires actions and have their titles changed; if they are more complicated than that then they ought to manage themselves with a few method calls.  It sounds like you might be worrying unnecessarily here.

Comment: Yes they just fire actions and have their titles changed, as you suggest. It sounds like you might be right :)